# AutoFlushWrapper with Mail target

Tags: nlog

I'm trying to send myself an email with the latest log entries when an error occurs. But I don't want to receive any mail unless an actual ERROR-level entry have been logged, so I've set the `bufferSize` to a big number. My problem is, the mail target isn't being triggered when the ERROR-level entry is logged, only when the actual `bufferSize` is hit, meaning I'm not receiving any mails at all since the `bufferSize` is so big. My `NLog.config` up like this:

```xml
<targets>
  <target name="mailautoflush" xsi:type="AutoFlushWrapper" condition="level >= LogLevel.Error">
    <target name="mailbuffer" xsi:type="BufferingWrapper" bufferSize="1000000">
      <target name="mail" xsi:type="Mail" ... />
    </target>
  </target>
</targets>
<rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="mailautoflush"></logger>
</rules>
```

What am I doing wrong? Also, is there a better way to do this? Using the AutoFlushWrapper/BufferingWrapper trick seems like a hack. Thanks!

Comment: is this NLog 4.4+?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It only executes the flush after the triggering LogEvent has reported that it has reached its final target. Since the LogEvent is parked in the buffer, then the flush is never fired.

Created PR: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/pull/2042

Comment: Thank you for creating a PR. As someone who doesn't really have time to dig into the inner workings of NLog, it would be great if something like this was accepted and merged into the master branch.

Answer (score 0):

You code looks valid.

> Also, is there a better way to do this? Using the AutoFlushWrapper/BufferingWrapper trick seems like a hack. Thanks!

It's more like a modular design - you can combine blocks with each other.

Comment: Alright, I'll look more into the problem then. The code above was actually based on one of your previous answers, which is why I was confused as to why it doesn't work.